# weblogic.ant.taskdefs.webservices.javaschema.JavaSchema jar file

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic12g

I am working on an upgrading weblogic from 9.2.3 to 12.1.3.

The utility autotype is depricated see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24487/utils.htm#ADMRF117

Now I need to create an ant task, but I can't find the jar including the class in title

Any help can be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe this task has moved into the following jar:

```
<weblogic install dir>/server/lib/webservices.jar
```

One convenient way to search for where a class lives is to run a script like the following. I ran this inside of `<weblogic install dir>/server/lib`:

```
#!/bin/sh

LOOK_FOR="JavaSchema"

for i in `find . -name "*jar"`
do
  echo "Looking in $i ..."
  jar tvf $i | grep $LOOK_FOR > /dev/null
  if [ $? == 0 ]
  then
    echo "================> Found \"$LOOK_FOR\" in $i"
    break
  fi
done
```